# Simple Timer with Start, Pause and Stop in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

```
    private void btn_Start_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        RunTimer(true);
    }

    private void btn_Pause_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        RunTimer(false);
    }
    public void RunTimer(Boolean Value)
    {
        Boolean excuteTimer = Value;
        TimeSpan TimeElement = new TimeSpan();

        Device.StartTimer(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1), () =>
        {
            if (Value)
            {
                TotalTime = TotalTime + TimeElement.Add(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1));
                label.Text = string.Format("{0:hh\\:mm\\:ss}", TotalTime);
                // returning true will fire task again in 2 minutes.
                return true;
            }

            // No longer need to recur. Stops firing task
            return false;
        });


    }
```

I am trying to run a timer every one sec. It runs well but when pause is clicked, it does not stop until start is clicked again.

Answer (score 1):

The Device.StartTimer command starts a independently thread once it is called. When you click Start, the parameter Value inside the StartTimer thread will be always true;

I suggest you move the Value variable outside the thread, put it in the class level and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how exactly this works , but I think that it works like this. 
everytime you hit RunTimer, a thread is created to run the timer, so when you press Start , the timer starts and ruccur every one second . However, when you press Pause , according to your code the first thread would keep running because so far it did not return false yet. That is why your pause does not work . 
To solve it , try making Value as a global field (make it a private member), and return it instead of true or false, this way when you click pause you make "Value" false.

```
private bool _isRunning; 

private void btn_Start_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    _isRunning=true; 
    RunTimer();
}

private void btn_Pause_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    _isRunning=false;
}
public void RunTimer()
{

    TimeSpan TimeElement = new TimeSpan();
    Device.StartTimer(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1), () =>
    {

            TotalTime = TotalTime + TimeElement.Add(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1));
            label.Text = string.Format("{0:hh\\:mm\\:ss}", TotalTime);
            // returning true will fire task again in 2 minutes.
            return _isRunning;
    });
}
```

I hope this works for you , I have not tried it myself , just using my logic ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can change your code with the code below:

```
public void RunTimer(Boolean value) 
{
    Boolean executeTimer = value;            
    Device.StartTimer(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1), () => 
    {                
        string LblText = "";                            
        if (value)                
        {                    
            TotalTime = TotalTime - TimeElement.Add(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1));                                    
            SMSSendLableText = string.Format("{0:hh\\:mm\\:ss}", TotalTime);                    
            return true;
        }                
        else                
        {                    
            return false;                
        }            
    });
}
```